# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1364

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Field 'end_time' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `quiz_result` (`uid`, `quid`, `oids`, `qids`, `category_name`, `qids_range`, `start_time`, `last_response`, `time_spent`, `time_spent_ind`, `institute_id`, `photo`) VALUES ('1', '2', '0,0,0,0,0', '1,2,6,4,3', 'General', '0-4', 1457200638, 1457200638, '0', '0,0,0,0,0', '1', '')

Filename: C:\wamp\www\online_test\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: what is your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You have a field named `'end_time'` in a the table `quiz_result` that has been declared as `NOT NULL` (therefore the error `Field 'end_time' doesn't have a default value` each time you do not (or forgot) to provide a value for that column in each `INSERT`s). Check the column list and the column `end_time` is nowhere to be found.

You must either re-declare your table by setting a default value for it or provide a value for the column 'end_time' each time you insert a row to that table.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved hosting, and my web bug : Error Number: 1364

Field 'LuotXem' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `baiviet` (`TieuDe`, `Loai`, `Link`, `Title`, `H1`, `H2`, `Keyword`, `Description`, `NoiBat`, `NoiDung`, `TrangThai`, `NguoiGui`, `MenuCha`, `CapMenu`, `ViTri`) VALUES ('dsaf', 'Banner', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '

ádfasd
\n', '1', '5', 0, 1, 'TOP')

Filename: /home/thanhdlk33/public_html/batdongsan3mien.com/models/default_model.php

Line Number: 13

file default_model.php :

```
<?php
```

error_reporting(0);
class Default_model extends CI_Model{

```
function __contruct() 
{ 
    parrent::__contruct(); 

} 

//--- Them dong du lieu moi voi du lieu dau vao la 1 mang
function addDuLieuMoi($table,$data){
    if($this->db->insert($table,$data))
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try checking case of of variables, because some db are case sensitive.

Comment: May I ask if what are variables has to do with the problem if the errors pertain to the executed query?

Comment: Please see my answer above.